# What is the meaning of "Feet come in twos in socks and shoes"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Feet come in twos in socks and shoes" in the following sentence (source: Feet are Neat!),

> **Feet come in twos in socks and shoes**, two boots with zippers, two
>   bunny slippers, two swimming fins. Feet are twins.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When things "come in twos", that means that those things are generally found with another, in a pair. People usually have two feet, and therefore need two shoes and two socks. The phrase seems to be made to rhyme for children.

In general, if things come in [number expressed as a plural], we mean that they are usually found, sold, supplied etc, in collections of that number.

Some superstitious people believe that lucky or unlucky events "come in threes", that is, if they have had what they perceive as two such events, a third one will soon happen. In British shops, eggs usually come in 'dozens' (twelves) and 'half-dozens'  (sixes).

Comment: If so, does "Feet come in twos in socks and shoes" mean "Feet are usually found in collections of two when we want to put on socks and shoes" ?

Comment: Yes, but that would destroy the rhyme.